# Resharper StackOverflowException

Tags: resharper, xunit

Sometimes when I run my unit tests, the test runner throws a `StackOverflowException`. Is there a way to see which test possibly causes the problem. Because I am unable to pinpoint where to problem lies.

Any tips? Or general causes for this problem?

Comment: do you have any for or while loop that you forgot to break? If the loops are infinite it would throw StackoverflowException

Comment: @jackjop no while loops or for loops used in any of the tests

Comment: can you please check [this link](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206083519-Junit-test-and-stack-overflow-exception)? Maybe you have the same problem, infinite property calling or similar

Comment: also [this](https://gist.github.com/jokcofbut/7358419) you might have similar things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the MSDN page on [StackOverflowExceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stackoverflowexception?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2):

> In the .NET Framework 1.0 and 1.1, you could catch a StackOverflowException object (for example, to recover from unbounded recursion). Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, you can’t catch a StackOverflowException object with a try/catch block, and the corresponding process is terminated by default. Consequently, you should write your code to detect and prevent a stack overflow. For example, if your app depends on recursion, use a counter or a state condition to terminate the recursive loop. The following example uses a counter to ensure that the number of recursive calls to the Execute method do not exceed a maximum defined by the MAX_RECURSIVE_CALLS constant

So this makes Resharper hard to catch `StackOverflowException`s too. You should check your code to see if there are endless recursive calls, such as methods, functions, properties. Other than that, you can try the code in the `MSDN` link I shared. But you have no other options.

Comment: @sertsdat it was indeed a recursive method in the project who was causing the problem. Thanks for the suggestion.